# Add delay to code execution in C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, delay, cocos2d-x-3.0

Say I need to call a function with 2 seconds delay. In cocos2d-x you can use actions:

```
auto action = Sequence::create(
    DelayTime::create(2), 
    CallFunc::create(
        [&]() {
            // here is the lambda function that does whatever you want after 2 seconds
        }
    ), 
    NULL
);

runAction(action);
```

But in order to run the action you need a `Node`, which in not always available. There are classes that have nothing to do with the `Node`. **So I wonder what is the cross-platform way of adding delay to code execution in C++11?**

Comment: To add to @Shaktal answer below, I subclass std::thread so I can have an implementation with custom variables, etc that I use to decide the state of the thread, what to do with it, etc. I also create a bunch of threads at game start-up that run specific tasks at specific times.

Comment: @GameDeveloper I did not understand your point, sorry.

Comment: what did you not understand? Perhaps look at this: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) function added in the C++11 threading library:

```
std::chrono::seconds duration( 2 ); 
std::this_thread::sleep_for( duration ); // Sleep for 2 seconds.
```

This will cause the current thread to halt execution for the duration specified in the `duration` object.

Comment: Is there any better way? Windows shows a circle on the mouse as if the windows is freezed.

Comment: Well, yes it would as this will pause the execution of the main thread if that is where you are executing it.

Comment: Is there a way to add async delay?

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: Perform this in a new thread and fire callback on main thread after delay

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this question is closed, anyway you can use Scheduler to schedule your method to get called anytime in Cocos2dx.
In your class init method before returning true do something like this.

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::setGamePlaySpeed), .2);
```

and create a method giving it float dt as argument like this..

```
void HelloWorld::setGamePlaySpeed(float dt){
 // do anything yo want... This method will be Called every .2 seconds
 }
```

Now float dt is the dt time you specified in your scheduler.
Hope this Helps anyone looking for same issue in Future...

Comment: this is a good approach if your class is derived from `Node`. But what if you didn't derive it? You just have an arbitrary class. Can you use an instance of a `Node` in that case?

Comment: you can also Try getting system time in Milliseconds and then after a set timeframe call the function in your arbitrary class. You can do something like that to get system time in Milliseconds. static inline long millisecondNow()
{
    struct cc_timeval now;
    CCTime::gettimeofdayCocos2d(&now, NULL);
    return (now.tv_sec * 1000 + now.tv_usec / 1000);
}

Comment: how you use the `pThread`. Is it cross platform? Does it freeze the main thread like it is in the case of `std::this_thread::sleep_for( duration );`

Comment: GameDeveloper shared a link above which shows how to use threads, i don't understand what do you want to achieve with this, If you want to stop the execution of whole game(no logic calls for specified time) then you can use above method in my comments and pause/Resume Director as seems fit, if you want to just call a method every few timeframes then also you can do it by using same menthod

Comment: I load the assets asynchronously after showing splash screen. Then I look how much time is elapsed when loading is done. If it is less then 2 seconds, I want to wait `2 - duration` seconds to retain the splash screen. Only then I want to change the scene.

Comment: Sorry for delay i was Busy, Ok you can use AssetsManager and AssetsManagerDelegateProtocols class for loading your resources asynchronously,it provides callback methods you can use for loading/downloading progress of assets, in onSuccess Method you just remove your splash screen from director. Refer these links http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0beta/df/d02/classcocos2d_1_1extension_1_1_assets_manager.html#a891bfe62270fcd104c083f3df9b060fb

Comment: and http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0beta/d7/d69/classcocos2d_1_1extension_1_1_assets_manager_delegate_protocol.html#a85ec5d98b76757692e55d083ea55f610  Please Note to use these classes you need to include #include "cocos-ext.h"
#include "assets-manager/AssetsManager.h" in your .cpp file and also use USING_NS_CC_EXT; as namespace

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I didn't know about this class. But I don't understand how to load spritesheets using AssetsManager. I see it is being used for loading specific files according to Manifest format. And it only woks for cocos2d-JS (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/assets-manager/en). But I need to add spritsheet to the texture cache asynchronously instead of downloading from server. I don't see how this class can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use usleep function for that.

for that you have to include

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

in your class and where you need a pause you can put usleep function like this.

```
usleep(5000000);
```

and then call your function which you need to run .

this will put your game loop in a 5 second sleep mode.

Comment: is this standard? I thought this was UNIX only.